# How do I keep reading an endless stream with fail tolerance

Tags: c#, json, twitter, stream, deserialization

Currently i'm working on an app that reads the stream from a Twitter api and parses it into objects.
At the moment I read the stream and use ReadObject from DataContractJsonSerializer to make my objects.

This works great!!

HOWEVER:
I'm kind of worried what would happen in the off chance my program catches up with the stream (internet slows down or w/e) and there is not enough data to parse...The method will probably throw an exception, but i want to wait for new data and then retry the same object and continue.

Also i was wondering how i could make the method more stable, in case corrupt data would enter the stream or something like this.

Thanks in advance for any answers/ideas:)

Comment: You can only get an exception if the data is corrupted. Otherwise you will deserialize it as soon as you have enough data to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your program catches up with the twitter feed, the DCJS should just block until you get enough data to complete reading.  That isn't normally a concern, because streams are designed to hide latency from their readers.

Much more likely is that you won't catch up, but rather keep falling behind until you run out of memory, throw an OOME, and the program will crash.

I'd suggest rather than trying to parse the stream on the fly, write it to something like a file and read from that (maybe even in parallel, using rolling files or something).

Comment: Thank you for your reaction!

However, then i have a filestream, how can i catch mistakes in the stream?
I think the main thing i want to know: how do i find the next good peace of data. If i fall behind reading, eventually i'll want to skip a piece and continue at one of the newest parts in the file, this also requeres finding a good place to begin.

Though if i think about it, i doubt a pc would process data slower then it would receive from an internet stream, if processing means parsing it to a struct/class